# iTerm2: fix for choppy/jumpy cursor movement?

Tags: terminal, terminal.app, iterm2

I just started using iTerm2 and I'm loving it, *except* that cursor movement is smoother on the Terminal.app that comes with OSX. I have my key-repeat speed pretty high, which makes it more noticeable.

I made a short screencast comparing the two: http://youtu.be/t-xs_Mk5yMY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filled out a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=2859) and the good folks at iTerm fixed it! It's in the latest nightly build.